# Angular 6 call services several times instead of once

Tags: angular, rest, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using Angular 6 and RxJs 6. I have a problem with the service calling. I'm going to report a case, but it happens to me for all rest-api calls.

I have a list of items (templates). The user can go to edit and there is a save button. The problem is that, I don't know why, even if I click the button just one time, there are sent several calling. I tried to put a breakpoint, but it enters into the funciton just one time, so I can't figure out the problem. And there is an issue because in some cases the server (for example) create an item 2 times.

This is the save function in edit.component.ts:

```
saveTemplate(){
    const saveTemplate$ = this.templateService.saveTemplate(this.item);
    saveTemplate$.subscribe(
       data => {
          this.toastr.success('Saved');
     });
}
```

This is the funciton inside the template.service.ts:

```
saveTemplate(textTemplate Template) 
    return this.http.post<SenecaResponse<{ error: string, response: string }>>(this.saveTemplateUrl, {
        textTemplate: textTemplate
    })
}
```

This is a screen of the rest-api when I click the save button:
[image]

This is the HTTP-INTERCEPTOR:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) {
}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.store.select('auth')
        .pipe(take(1),
            switchMap((authState: fromAuth.AuthState) => {
                const headerSettings: { [name: string]: string | string[]; } = {};

                for (const key of req.headers.keys()) {
                    headerSettings[key] = req.headers.getAll(key);
                }
                if (authState.token) {
                    headerSettings['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authState.token;
                }
                headerSettings['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
                const newHeader = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings);

                const changedReq = req.clone({
                    headers: newHeader
                });

                return next.handle(changedReq);
            }));
}
```

}

Comment: My guess is that it's being called for multiple elements in the list

Comment: No no, I left the page list; in fact, the Id of the template that i'm passing to the rest-api calling is always the same.. and then, in the list, I have 6 elements

Comment: The weird thing is that sometime it makes 3, sometime 4

Comment: try to add breakpoint in you'r service function which is saveTemplate(textTemplate Template)

Comment: I re-tried right now, it enters in the saveTemplate(textTemplate: Template) just one time :/

Comment: I think we will need to see more of the code such as the list component itself to help debug this

Comment: I am sure you are calling your service several times. comment saveTemplate(textTemplate: Template) and see how many errors you will get in you'r component. alternatively you can stop start you'r project or clear node_module and install again.

Comment: I get just one error in the console: ERROR TypeError: this.templateService.saveTemplate is not a function

Comment: I updated my question with the HTTP interceptor, maybe is there the error... even if I put a breakpoint in interceptor, it enters just one time

Comment: @panagulis72 pblm solved ? i am also facing same like tat any suggestion?